# AWS lambda invocation locally

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam, serverless-offline

I have SQS -> triggers a lambda(code that needs to be tested) -> where its workflow -> can trigger other lambdas in multiple API Gateways (already deployed in AWS)

Is there a way I can emulate SQS locally so that I can test the lambda locally while also calling other lambdas that are deployed in AWS?

We already are using serverless-offline, which allows us to test a lambda locally.
What we are looking for to test is the following scenario SQS(local)-> lambda (local) -> lambda (on aws account)

the lambda makes calls to other lambda's like this. how can we emulate those locally?

```
params = {
                FunctionName: lambdaName,
                InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
                LogType: 'None',
                Payload: JSON.stringify(event)
            };
        }
        response = await lambda.invoke(params).promise();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LocalStack](https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/aws/feature-coverage/). Here you can find a tutorial on how to do that. https://rochisha-jaiswal70.medium.com/using-aws-lambda-with-amazon-simple-queue-service-bb0694257a2b

Comment: updated the question. can you tell me how we can do the 
 lambda (local) -> lambda (on aws account) or alternatively 
 lambda (local) -> lambda (different lambda locally)

Comment: It's not a good practice to call a Lambda directly from another one. You can use Step Functions instead. You can also place an API Gateway in front (in the case you have several Lambdas that can be  logically grouped).